# How to write correct if array value is empty or how to set to empty?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

let's take simple view element like

```
 {{ Form::select('license',$licenses, $selectedLicenses->value, array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
```

Depended controller returns

```
return View::make('user.cv.4', array('licenses'=> $licences,'selectedLicenses'   => $selectedLiceses,)
```

So problem is that if user first time create cv where `$licenses` will be `NULL` and compiler throw error like that `$selectedLicenses->value Trying to get property of non-object`.

So question is how to do that `$selectedLicenses->value` will be also NULL if parent variable `$selectedLiceses`? It is possible to do that without any if statements? I wanna keep my code as simple as I can.

I am using php, and laravel framework. My model looks like

```
class License extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'license';
    protected $fillable = array('value','licenseStart','licenseEnd');
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Comment: Short answer: no. If a variable is `NULL` then you can't _try_ to access properties of `NULL`, because that will always throw an exception. So you need to resort to using some conditional statements somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it without an if.

You could do it inline with a shorthand:

```
{{ Form::select('license',$licenses, ($selectedLicenses != null ? $selectedLicenses->value : null), array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
```

Or set value to null, before you inject it.

```
if($selectedLicenses == null){
    $selectedLicenses = (object) array('value' => null);
}
// return View::make etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case use Ternary Operator, like the following

```
$value = ($selectedLicenses) ? $selectedLicenses->value : '';
```

See, if that works.

Comment: This will still throw an exception because you try to get the property `value` from a non-object. You have to check `$selectedLicenses` itself (like in my answer...)